# How can I overcome "focus-stealer" prevention in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, registry

The `ShowWindow` function doesn't work as advertised any more and it's likely due to "focus stealing" restrictions, which I thought bypassed once I modified the `ForegroundLockTimeout` registry setting. Even though I set it to 0 everywhere in the Registry, my calls still fail.

I'm trying to use ShowWindow to pull some programs out of SysTray hiding via keyboard shortcuts. I bound some C# apps to those hotkeys. For example, I use this, to pull Total Commander out (as its standard functionality is broken):

```
//Win32API.ShowWindow((IntPtr)hwndTC, Win32API.ShowWindowCommand.ShowDefault);
Win32API.ShowWindow((IntPtr)hwndTC, Win32API.ShowWindowCommand.ShowMaximized);
//Win32API.ShowWindow((IntPtr)hwndTC, Win32API.ShowWindowCommand.Maximize);
//Win32API.SetWindowPos(hwndTC, Win32API.HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
//    Win32API.SWP_NOSIZE | Win32API.SWP_NOMOVE);
//Win32API.SetWindowPos(hwndTC, Win32API.HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
//    Win32API.SWP_NOSIZE | Win32API.SWP_NOMOVE);
Win32API.SetWindowPos(hwndTC, Win32API.HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    Win32API.SWP_NOSIZE | Win32API.SWP_NOMOVE | Win32API.SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
Win32API.SetForegroundWindow(hwndTC);
```

There is a lot of commented code because I tried everything. On Windows XP this worked perfectly with a simple call to ShowWindow. On Windows 7, it's a mess. It behaves chaotically and rarely works.

When running as an administrator, it *kind of* works. Except that the window I'm trying to show will start blinking on the taskbar instead of being shown. Complete mystery.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with ShowWindow, it is SetForegroundWindow that gets the special treatment.  You can't shove a window into the user's face when she's actively using another window.  The blinking button is the result.

Comment: @Zannjaminderson, did you read the question? The OP is trying to make these windows appear with a shortcut key, so the user *wants* the window to take focus...

Comment: Excuse me, I missed that part of the question.  My bad.  Comment removed.

Comment: It has several reasons that this isn't working consistently... some are UI related, some security related (which got tightened more and more over time)... IF you really really want to make this work you need to "hack" the respective process by injecting them with some code... BUT this ain't a production-quality solution IMHO... so: what is your goal ?

Comment: If you implement your hotkeys correctly (i.e. you use RegisterHotkey, not a keyboard hook) you should have focus privileges in that handler.

Comment: @HansPassant: what if I am the user and I want the window to be shoved in my face? Can't I tweak my own system to do it? Is there no way to accomplish this any more? Guess that's one of the prices of moving from XP to W7.

Comment: The rule is the last window that got the input event.  You posted the wrong code to help us help you.

Comment: @Hans Passant: but that's ALL the code. It works on XP. I don't understand what you mean by "the rule is the last window".

Comment: Well, there should be some code that makes this code run.  Something that pinvokes RegisterHotKey, a WndProc override, SetWindowsHookEx.  I can't see it from here.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I don't use any of that. The application is compiled as an EXE, as you see it, and I invoke the hotkey by associating a keyboard shortcut with it in the Start Menu (via the properties of the Shortcut to my application), or (I also tried this) via the HotKeyz application. So, the application is started, runs, and exits instantly. It just does its job and then it's dead. Really simple "hack". I needed nothing more, so why bother? But if you say that by going deeper I could solve this, then gladly, I will!

Comment: I would like to refer the poster to this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx.  It is not entirely the answer, but does a good deal of explaining why Windows 7 works the way it does.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I know why it works the way it does. It means Microsoft has to change the documentation of the ShowWindow and SetWindowPos to reflect all this more clearly. The functionality seems broken for now.